# Rename ControlTemplate in Expression Blend

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, xaml, expression-blend

We are working at training some of our Flash animators in Expression Blend.

One thing that has caught them up is that there is no way to rename a ControlTemplate from the UI once you have created it--I only see how to do it in code and XML freaks them out.

Here is a screenshot:

[image: New Template]

Once you go past this screen, the name you choose can't seem to be changed in Blend's UI.

We are using the [VS 2012 Blend+Sketchflow](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30702) preview, but I can't see how to do it in the copy of Blend that comes with VS 2012 or Blend 4 either.

Does anyone know if it's possible? If not, are there any cool extensions out there for Blend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look on the Resources tab. It will list all resources in scope of the currently open document and you can rename from there.

Either right-click > edit, or double click the name of the resource.

[image]

[image]